# How do i clear all results in powershell

Tags: powershell

When i first run a script in powershell, the email I’ve received is blank but there is a result displayed in the console. after i rerun it again, the displayed results in the email is from the previous execution. I’ve tried using clear-history and cls but it didnt work.

Example :
I run a script using previous date n current date. The email did not display any values

The second time i run the script using current month, the values in email content n html table is displayed from previous and current date

Comment: An easy way to clear results is to close the shell and open a new one. Please post the code in question

Comment: Sounds like you're assigning the email contents to some variable _after_ sending it. Please show us the code

Comment: Difficult to assess due received input but it sounds like some Clear-variable is required at some stage.

Comment: Could be a race condition